# Store JS toggle in localStorage with animation

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I want this to work with **slidetoggle**, but can't get it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/o52tkv1t/

If you **reload the page** with the above fiddle, the toggle **status is saved**. So that works! But now I want to have a nice animation with this show hide function.

```js
$('.a').click(function(){
$(".target").toggle();
var isVisible = $('.target').is(":visible"); 
localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
});
// stored in localStorage as string, `toggle` needs boolean
var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
$('.target').toggle(isVisible);
```

```css
body {padding:30px;}

.target {
  background:#9D0053;
  height:160px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="a">Button</button>
<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: Do you just want to slideToggle when clicked on button?
like this
https://jsfiddle.net/o52tkv1t/2/

or you want something else?

Comment: This depends on the type of animation you want, but a simple solution would be `slideToggle()`: https://jsfiddle.net/pj3gs0z9/. Also note that I simplified the localStorage property logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went with the solution and simplified logic of @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the type of animation you want, but a simple solution would be to use `slideToggle()`

```
$('.a').click(function() {
  $(".target").slideToggle(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('visible', $(this).is(":visible"));
  });
});

$('.target').toggle(localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'true');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pj3gs0z9)

Also note that I simplified the localStorage property logic